# My Table only shows the first Row then the rest is out of table

Tags: html, jsp

[my page created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KceP.png)

so im new to NetBeans and JSP and i was trying to display my Oracle SQL table in a web page but it only shows the first row insenter code hereide the table and the rest displays out of the table.

here is my code

```
%>
<%@page import = "java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import = "java.io.*" %>
<% Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");%>

        
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JSP Page connecting to Oracle 12c Table!</h1>
    
    <%
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@129.7.240.3:1521:ORCL";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"#####","#####");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from SALESTODATE" );
        %>
        
        <TABLE BORDER = "1" BGCOLOR =" CCFFFFF" width = '50%' cellspacing ='1' cellpadding =' 0 ' bordercolor ="black" border ='1'
               <TR>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size ='2' />Product ID</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size ='2' />TIMES ORDERED</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size ='2' />Product Description</TH>
        </TR>
        <% while (rs.next()){%>
        <TR>
         <TD> <font size =' 2' /><center><%= rs.getString("PRODUCTID")%></center></TD>
         <TD> <font size =' 2' /><center><%= rs.getString("TIMESORDERED")%></center></TD>
         <TD> <font size =' 2' /><center><%= rs.getString("PRODUCTDESCRIPTION")%></center></TD>
     
        </TR>
        </TABLE>  
        
        

        
        <%  }
        conn.close();
        %>
        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to move the

```
</table>
```

out of the while loop.